# Distributed Task Scheduling in Non-Clustered WSO2 EIs: Achieving Efficiency and High Availability

Tags: scheduled-tasks, wso2-esb, esb, wso2-micro-integrator, ei

I need to run a scheduler on two separate EIs without clustering. How can I distribute tasks between them or implement an active-passive failover scenario? Are there any other efficient solutions available? This is usually undesirable for non-clustered environments as it would lead to duplicate work and potential data inconsistencies.

How can I configure the scheduler to distribute different tasks to each EI and run them concurrently?